# SQL Data Pivot of Data

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table, where multiple data values are stored against a record of a column like this:

```
Table A         
RecordId    FieldNo Data    
1           1       A,B 
1           2       A   
1           3       A,B,C   
2           1       A   
2           2       NULL    
2           3       NULL    
3           1       NULL    
3           2       A,B 
3           3       NULL    
4           1       A,B,C   
4           2       NULL    
4           3       A,B
```

Note: The values e.g. A,B,C can be any data value, and can contain many sub-items, not just 3 as shown, this is just for illustration purposes.

The problem I have is I need to pivot the data, not only to extract each data item into a separate row, but also into to columns without repeating data as such:

```
Table B         
RecordId    F1      F2      F3
1           A       A       A
1           B       NULL    B
1           NULL    NULL    C
2           A       NULL    NULL
3           NULL    A       NULL
3           NULL    B       NULL
4           A       NULL    A
4           B       NULL    B
4           C       NULL    NULL
```

I have struggled with this. Can anyone shed some light on a approach to doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Uh, can you change the database design? That would be the real solution.

Comment: What @Jacob H said. You should normalize your db structure and your problem solves itself.

Comment: Appreciate the answers, I would have said the same, but without going into detail the DB design is fine. I just need to know if its possible.

Comment: I say fine, I can't change it, its out of my control ;-(